# Trying to compile lecture notes on just an iphone

Tags: compiling, document-classes

Here's the source code of the tex file: http://pastebin.com/g6TfhMVi
Here's the source of the notes.cls file:
http://pastebin.com/FLLLS36F

Right now I only have an iPhone and no other computers.
I have tried using the VerbTex (Verbosus) app in conjunction with Dropbox and it returns with a whole bunch of errors. Here are just some of them (the log is huge):

```
'This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
entering extended mode
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(./notes.cls

! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

l.1 \\P
       rovidesClass{notes}[1999/09/17]

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

I also tried using LaTeX Lab but I couldn't figure out how to upload the `.cls` file.

I think I'm missing something big here (older LaTeX language?) because these lecture notes should work, and they've been used before.

Comment: Why don't you try ShareLaTeX or WriteLaTeX for the same purpose. These are online LaTeX Compilers that can help you out.

Comment: Ok I will try that now and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Steps

1. Register in ShareLaTeX
2. Sign in with the same account
3. Create a new project in ShareLaTeX
4. On the left you will have your directory contents with the file `main.tex`.
5. Paste the code (not the class contents `notes`) here
6. Create a new file named `notes.cls` rather than `notes.tex` (default) and paste the code of the corresponding class.
7. Now, it will compile.

The result of the compilation from the ShareLaTeX compiler. It compiled successfully. A sample screenshot of the editor, titlepage and the content page are:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: nice.. how did you do that? I got 1300 errors when I just tried that. Where did you put notes.cls?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/akaog9/8 What am I missing here?

Comment: @user1564795 see the edited answer

Comment: You must have not pasted the code for the `notes` class in `notes.cls`. The error log is because of that. @user1564795

Comment: ok i had uploaded the the cls file via dropbox, which altered the code by adding another slash for some reason. I am looking for a way to paste it via iphone now. it can't paste normally

Comment: did it with cloudbrowse app.

Comment: @user1564795 you can up vote the answer if you like it ;)